# Unexpected Optional behavior with Python3 typing and mypy

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm new to using `typing` and `mypy`.

With the below block of code, `mypy` complains that `ret` cannot be assigned `None` because `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "Tuple[Connection, Cursor]") (python-mypy)`.

```
    def __connect__(self) -> Tuple[Optional[Tuple[Conn, Cursor]], Status]:
        """Establish DB connection."""
        if self.db_type is DB_Type.SQLITE:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            ret, status = (conn, cur), Status(Code.OK)
        else:
            ret, status = None, self.INVALID_STATUS    # mypy error 
        return ret, status
```

But I'm defining the return type signature as `Optional[Tuple[Connection, Cursor]`, instead of `Tuple[Connection, Cursor]`. So either I'm overlooking something, or there is a limitation in `mypy` static analysis, for which there is probably some workaround... pointers much appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't recreate bug. try making small changes to the code and rerun mypy, sometimes old errors persist.

Comment: PS my versions are Python 3.9.1 and mypy 0.800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`mypy` deals with untyped variables by using the type of the first assignment as the type of the variable.* So having two assignments to the same untyped variable with different types is considered a type mismatch. For example:

```
$ cat test.py 
foo, bar = 1, 2
foo, bar = None, 2
$ mypy test.py 
test.py:2: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "int")  [assignment]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The same issue is happening in your code, although it's less obvious: `ret` is assigned the type `Tuple[Connection, Cursor]`, but another branch is assigning `None` to `ret`. The return type is irrelevant.

One workaround is to set an explicity type `ret: Optional[Tuple[Connection, Cursor]]`.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! I'll have to read more about `mypy`'s type analysis, I can see it's a bit different from purely functional contexts since there are side effects to consider